# iOS library for formating html

Tags: html, ios, core-text

I am currently using Core Text to display a few text.But I found that unformatted html string is not supported by Core Text.So if there is any library can format a piece of html string?thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Cocoanetics [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) for this and it works great.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AboutMonkeys" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:data documentAttributes:NULL];

self.attributedTextView.attributedString = attributedString;
self.attributedTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

[Here is an article](http://behindtechlines.com/2012/05/display-html-strings-plaintext-ios/) that discusses this further